# How do you use negative coordinates with SRID 0 and DB2 Spatial?

Tags: coordinate-system, srid, db2

I'm trying to store pure Geometry values in DB2 on a flat plane, no spatial reference or projection, apologies on the nomenclature as I might be a little off, basically planar cartesian coordinates. So from what I can see I need to specify SRID 0. However, it seems I can't store negative values with SRID 0. I have a table with 2 columns "GeometryName" VARCHAR(30) and "GeometryData" DB2GSE.ST_GEOMETRY. When I try to insert values like so:

```
INSERT INTO "geometry_tests"."spatial_reference" ("GeometryName", "GeometryData") 
VALUES ('PY0', db2gse.ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON ((-1 1, -2 1, -2 2, -1 2, -1 1))', 0))
```

I get the following error:

```
SQL Error [38SSG]: Routine "DB2GSE.GSEGEOMFROMWKT" (specific name "GSEGEOMWKT1") has returned an error SQLSTATE with diagnostic text "GSE3416N  Coordinate out of bounds.".. SQLCODE=-443, SQLSTATE=38SSG, DRIVER=4.31.10
```

I tracked this down to negative coordinates. Other SRID's will accept negative values. How am I supposed to store negative coordinates where I don't want a spatial reference system? Just a regular Cartesian plane, with negative coordinates.

Comment: You *can't* store negative coordinates in SRID 0. Period. If you want negative coordinates, you need a spatial reference system. Actually, you **always** want a spatial reference system, because doing without one will only cause trouble. The [Understanding Coordinate Management whitepaper](https://downloads.esri.com/support/whitepapers/ao_/J9655_Understanding_Coordinate_Management_Esri_Whitepaper.pdf) explains why you can't store negative values in DB2's ST_GEOMETRY without a spatial reference using a negative false origin.

Comment: This DB2 documentation seems to explain the same, the values are stored into DB2 as positive integers. But this https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=functions-st-srid-st-srsid suggests that SRID 1 might work for you. Or maybe it is limited to -180 / -90 degrees.

Comment: You can store negative coordinates in a number of other databases with SRID 0, Oracle, MySql, SQL Server and Postgres. If there is an SRID that allows me to store geometries like I've mentioned above then that will work. I'm not storing map coordinates. This is purely for geometric math.